# Using Repository pattern in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

so i am new in Laravel.
I want to use repository pattern, and here my problem:

---

here is my interface:

```
namespace Repositories\User;

interface IUserRepository
{
public function getAllUsers();
}
```

here my class:

```
namespace Repositories\User;

use models\User;

class UserRepository implements IUserRepository
{
public function getAllUsers()
{
    return User::all();
}
}
```

here my controller:

```
class UserController extends \BaseController {

protected $user;

public function __contruct(IUserRepository $user)
{

    $this->user = $user;
}
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $users = $this->user->getAllUsers();

    return View::make('index');
}
}
```

i register it in boostrap\start.php

```
App::bind('Repositories\User\IUserRepository', 'Repositories\User\UserRepository');
```

i think it can run smooth but it is a result i get :( :

```
Call to a member function getAllUsers() on a non-object
$users = $this->user->getAllUsers();
```

So why? :(( Thanks for helping!

Comment: Have you tried `public function __contruct(Repositories\User\IUserRepository $user)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you infect that repo, then use namespace:

```
public function __contruct(Repositories\User\IUserRepository $user)
{

    $this->user = $user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you it work :x
But why i use
use Repositories\User;
    public function __contruct(IUserRepository        $user)
    {
    
        $this->user = $user;
    }
it didn't find the IUserRepository

Comment: Because this is how Reflection works. There is no `IUserRepository` in the global namespace, so you need to specify it directly.